# Run IO computations in parallel in Java8

Tags: java, java-8

I'm familiar with functional programming languages, usually in Scala and Javascript. I'm working on a Java8 project and not sure how I am supposed to run through a list/stream of item, and perform some side-effect for each of them in parallel, using a custom thread pool, and return an object on which it's possible to listen for completion (wether it's a success or failure).

Currently I have the following code, it seems to work (I'm using Play framework Promise implementation as return) but it seems not ideal because ForkJoinPool is not meant to be used for IO intensive computations in the first place.

```
public static F.Promise<Void> performAllItemsBackup(Stream<Item> items) {
    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(3);
    ForkJoinTask<F.Promise<Void>> result = pool
            .submit(() -> {
                try {
                    items.parallel().forEach(performSingleItemBackup);
                    return F.Promise.<Void>pure(null);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return F.Promise.<Void>throwing(e);
                }
            });

    try {
        return result.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to get result", e);
    }
}
```

Can someone give me a more idiomatic implementation of the above function? Ideally not using the ForkJoinPool, using a more standard return type, and most recent Java8 APIs? Not sure what I'm supposed to use between CompletableFuture, CompletionStage, ForkJoinTask...

Comment: Remember that Java isn't a functional language, and even though they added some *functionality* with Java 8, it's still an add-on in a similar way as generics were in Java 5. So what are you hoping for here? You want to execute your backup tasks in parallel and if a single one of them fails, you want an exception to be thrown...what about any tasks that may not have finished yet?

Comment: You might consider introducing Kotlin into your project, it takes just a single Maven dependency to do it. Its Coroutines feature turns promise-based code style into simple procedural style with no (explicit) callbacks. Coroutines are still experimental, but already quite mature.

Comment: @Kayaman I don't want an exception to be thrown, I want an exception to be returned asynchronously in the return type (which is what CompletableFuture seems for). If one task fails, I don't care if other pending tasks are cancelled or not because my backup is handled in a transactional and incremental way

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I'll have to take a look but honnestly I'm already perfectly fine with Scala for such tasks, and it's not negociable to introduce a new language to the project.

Comment: One of the advantages of Kotlin is near-perfect interoperability with Java, in both directions. The language itself is quite close to Java, there's a natural mapping between the two.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik It's certainly true but it's also true for Scala and interop has never been a problem for me. Plus I'm using Play framework (built with Scala) in a Java app, and it's easier to use the Play framework with Scala so Scala looks to me more suited for my usecase ;)

Comment: Yes, i forgot that detail about Play :) I've had some less than comfortable experiences with calling Scala from Java. The other way it's fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A canonical solution would be

```
public static CompletableFuture<Void> performAllItemsBackup(Stream<Item> items) {
    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(3);
    try {
        return CompletableFuture.allOf(
            items.map(CompletableFuture::completedFuture)
                 .map(f -> f.thenAcceptAsync(performSingleItemBackup, pool))
                 .toArray(CompletableFuture<?>[]::new));
    } finally {
        pool.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Note that the interaction between ForkJoin pool and parallel streams is an unspecified implementation detail you should not rely on. In contrast, `CompletableFuture` provides a dedicated API for providing an `Executor`. It doesn’t even have to be a `ForkJoinPool`:

```
public static CompletableFuture<Void> performAllItemsBackup(Stream<Item> items) {
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    try {
        return CompletableFuture.allOf(
            items.map(CompletableFuture::completedFuture)
                 .map(f -> f.thenAcceptAsync(performSingleItemBackup, pool))
                 .toArray(CompletableFuture<?>[]::new));
    } finally {
        pool.shutdown();
    }
}
```

In either case, you should shut down the executor explicitly instead of relying on automatic cleanup.

If you need a `F.Promise<Void>` result, you can use

```
public static F.Promise<Void> performAllItemsBackup(Stream<Item> items) {
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    try {
        return CompletableFuture.allOf(
            items.map(CompletableFuture::completedFuture)
                 .map(f -> f.thenAcceptAsync(performSingleItemBackup, pool))
                 .toArray(CompletableFuture<?>[]::new))
            .handle((v, e) -> e!=null? F.Promise.<Void>throwing(e): F.Promise.pure(v))
            .join();
    } finally {
        pool.shutdown();
    }
}
```

But note that this, like your original code, only returns when the operation has been completed, while the methods returning a `CompletableFuture` allow the operations to run asynchronously until the caller invokes `join` or `get`.

To return a truly asynchronous `Promise`, you have to wrap the entire operation, e.g.

```
public static F.Promise<Void> performAllItemsBackup(Stream<Item> stream) {
    return F.Promise.pure(stream).flatMap(items -> {
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        try {
            return CompletableFuture.allOf(
                items.map(CompletableFuture::completedFuture)
                     .map(f -> f.thenAcceptAsync(performSingleItemBackup, pool))
                     .toArray(CompletableFuture<?>[]::new))
                .handle((v, e) -> e!=null? F.Promise.<Void>throwing(e): F.Promise.pure(v))
                .join();
        } finally {
            pool.shutdown();
        }
    });
}
```

But it’s better to decide for one API instead of jumping back and forth between two different APIs.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I find the Java8 API quite complex compared to other languages, however I can follow how it works. I don't particularly want to stick to Play promise and I'm fine with a more portable return type like CompletableFuture

Comment: Depending on your needs, you could use `r -> new Thread(r).start()` as `Executor`, which creates a new thread for each task and doesn’t need to be shut down. Then, the code reduces to the four lines `return` statement of the second variant. I know, other languages can do it even shorter…